Minimize $\sqrt{9x²+144}-x$ without calculus
How to find mimumum value of $\sqrt{9x²+144}-x$ for $x>0$ without calculus. I am spesificly looking for solution with QM-AM or CS inequality (If it is solvable with these, I tried to apply them but could not find a way to do it). Thanks in advance.

Write $f(x) = \sqrt{9x^2 + 144} - x = 3\sqrt{x^2+16}-x$, now write $x = 4\tan{\theta}$, then
\begin{align*}
&f(x) = 3\sqrt{16\tan^2{\theta}+16} - 4\tan{\theta} = 12\sec{\theta}-4\tan{\theta} = 4\frac{(3-\sin{\theta})}{\cos{\theta}} \\
&f(x)\cos{\theta} = 12 - 4\sin{\theta} \\
&4\sin{\theta} + f(x)\cos{\theta} = 12 \\
&\left(\sqrt{f^2(x)+16}\right) \sin{(\theta + \alpha)} = 12
\end{align*}
where $\alpha = \alpha(x)$ is the angle such that
\begin{align*}
&\cos{\alpha} = \frac{4}{\sqrt{f^2(x)+16}} \\
&\sin{\alpha} = \frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{f^2(x)+16}}
\end{align*}
hence (since $\sqrt{f^2(x)+16} > 0$ and $12 > 0$, we have $0 < \sin{(\theta + \alpha) \geq 1$):
$$
\sqrt{f^2(x)+16} = \frac{12}{\sin{(\theta + \alpha)}} \geq 12
$$
so
$$
f^2(x) + 16 \geq 144 \Longrightarrow f(x) \geq 8\sqrt{2},
$$
now you're left to see that $f(x) = 8\sqrt{2}$ has a solution, but in fact $f(\sqrt{2}) = 8\sqrt{2}$, so this is your minimum.
Obs: In the end I used that the function is always positive to get the lower bound, but this is true due to QM-AM inequality, because if $x>0$:
$$
\sqrt{9x^2+144} - x \geq \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(3x+12) - x = 6\sqrt{2} + \frac{(3\sqrt{2}-2)x}{2} > 0.
$$
